# How to get Error message from REST service and show it at proper form field in java EE?

Tags: rest, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7, jersey-2.0

I made a Dynamic web project using Eclipse IDE. I made a simple web app for learning.

I also made a REST service (jersey implementation) which i am using for insert,update,delete and for listing records from mysql database.

Now i want that i've a registration form which has some fields. I want that before inserting the data into database using my REST service, the service should validate form data.

I searched a lot google. I understand how to validate data in my service. But i am not getting that how to show the error message to individual form field to client.

Is there any complete example of this which does not use maven and show me the whole working from submitting form to show the error messages.

Thanks in advance..please help me guys..

Comment: Please help me...i didn't even get a single comment, did i ask something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your approach slightly to solve this problem and implement it in the following way:

1. First of all You should add validation mechanisms on the client side and send registration request only when this validation will be successful.

   You will find form validation tutorial for `AngularJS` here:

   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

   http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

   and for `jQuery` here:

   http://runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation
2. Server should respond with propper HTTP statuses (with optional message). For example:

   `200 OK` (or `201 Created`) - when registration finished successfully;

   `400 Bad Request` - when registration cannot be finished successfully;

So in Your actual use case:

1. User fills HTML form inputs;
2. Inserted data are validated on the client side;
3. When data are invalid, error message is shown in the propper place (individual form field);
4. When data are correct request is sent to the serwer;
5. Server application tries to insert supplied data to database;
6. If operation is finished properly, server will answer with `200` (or `201`) status code. Registration is finished.
7. If operation is not finished properly, server will answer with `400`. Client (`AngularJS`, `jQuery`, `JS`) will show error message.

Hopefully, my answer will help You. Ask if You need more explanation.

Comment: First of all i really appreciate your answer, you explain each and everything in a simple and meaningful manner, really thanks to you from the depth of my heart. I understood what you suggest, but i ask just one thing for my info that is it meaningful to validate the data in my service method.If it is meaningful then why? Please explain this to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is meaningful. You should always validate data come from 'outside world' and You should never trust data come from 'outside world'. Without validation on the server side anyone can send something harmful. You should also validate data on several levels. On `DB` level (constraints, foreign keys) and on `Java` code.